# Queued Jobs are still processed even without Supervisor running

Tags: linux, laravel, supervisord

This seems weird. I killed all existing processes related to supervisord on my linux server (aws ec2) but the queued jobs are still being processed/worked on.

I checked the processes through `ps -fe` and I don't find any process of supervisord running.

Anyone who can tell me what's going on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what queue driver are you using in your .env file? sync, database, redis?

Comment: You might have the queue driver set to `sync`, which would run the jobs immediately without sending them to the queue. Even if you've updated the .env file, the older config might've been cached. Run `php artisan config:clear` to make sure the application uses the correct queue driver.

Comment: @lewis4u I'm using database driver

Comment: @Sandeesh Oh thank you, I'll try to check that one.

Comment: @Sandeesh oh you're right, I'm really using the sync driver, I'm a bummer.

Comment: @KenthJohnIsrael glad i could help

Comment: @Sandeesh you should add an answer too so that i can upvote it

Comment: @KenthJohnIsrael added my response as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to summarize this question up, for supervisor to be in charge of queuing make sure to set queue driver to `QUEUE_DRIVER=database` or `QUEUE_DRIVER=redis` in your .env file.

If queue driver is set to `QUEUE_DRIVER=sync` then all the jobs will be processed right away one by one and supervisor is not important at all, it doesn't even have to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

You might have the queue driver set to `sync`, which would run the jobs immediately without sending them to the queue. Even if you've updated the .env file, the older config might've been cached. Run `php artisan config:clear` to make sure the application uses the correct queue driver.